# How to handle special mime types and document formats in Liferay DMS

Tags: java, liferay, document, dms

Liferay 6.1 DMS ( Documents & Media Portlet ) has been super so far - recognizing metadata and previewing popular documents formats like doc, xls, pdf, txt etc.

However my corporation has special needs. Some of our clients want us to provide special handling ( online viewing and editing ) of some other formats like *.ai, *.psd documents like it's done in Google Docs and similar cloud-based document management software.

We already have special code that addresses these formats. However we are not quite sure about how to extend the Liferay DMS such that it shows our special preview and editor when these formats are selected in the DMS.

Does anyone have a clue? Perhaps it's possible to extend the DMS by adding a button?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can try EXT plugin to include your special code for the formats, and modify some JSPs in DMS portlet and may be add your own based on requirement.

For a high level example you can modify the JSP which shows the list of files and then on click of the file you can check for the type in the action class and accordingly handle it or let Liferay handle it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go for a document library hook?

Extend and override all the methods in:

`com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook`